# Validation spanning a group of text boxes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, validation

I'm trying to achieve the following:
[image]

Where:

- Surname is always required
- NI Number OR Reference Number is required

Is this beyond the scope of the [ASP.NET Validation Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx)?  The only solution I can think of is writing some bespoke javascript (for client side) and backing that up with some server side code.

Comment: I suspect custom code may be the way to go here :-( This would be tricky to implement even with a `CustomValidator`, since the validation controls are designed to work on a single control, not across a group of controls e.g. in a `CustomValidator`'s server-side method, you pass in a `Value` parameter - which textbox's Text property are you going to pass in that instance? Do you apply the validator to just one textbox or both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is to have a `CustomValidator`([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) check that both textboxes are not
empty. Then validate both textboxes with a regular expression. The expression should check for either a valid entry **OR** a blank field.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CustomValidator and handle it there

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx#aspnet-validateaspnetservercontrols_topic7